# I need xpath to extract this kind of code from website

Tags: email, xpath, extract, import.io

I'm using import.io to extract informations from a website but I'm stucked on the email field only. I managed to extract other information, but this is a little bit confusing for me.

This is the code on the website that I need to extract. And the website has several values with this kind of code, several email addresses.

```
<td valign="top"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" class="text_black-11">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="35" align="center" class="text_02-11"><img width="16" height="16" src="/interface/icon_www.png"></td>
    <td class="text_02-11"><a target="" href="http://www.website.com" class="text_02-11">Visit Website</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="35" align="center" class="text_02-11"><img width="19" height="12" src="/interface/icon_email.png"></td>
    <td class="text_02-11"><a target="" href="mailto:info@mail.com" class="text_02-11">Send Email</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is there anything unique with this element? Can you post the entire HTML?

Comment: I've edited the code in my question with complete code.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't target the email directly and it always comes as an `href`inside an `a` tag with `mailto`
you can try this

```
//a[contains (@href, 'mailto:')]/@href
```

or

```
//a[contains (., 'Send Email')]/@href
```

if the website is constructed this way

also if you want to clean that field after selection you can add this regex to the regex field inside import.io

```
(?<=mailto:).*
```

just make sure that the xpath works first